# Plot several segments with a partially common legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend, segment

Say that I have the following data frame:

```
line_df <- data.frame(x_ini = c(0.55,2.55,1.55,5.55,7.55),
x_end = c(1.45,3.45,2.45,6.45,8.45),
y = c(-0.5,-0.5,-1.5,-2.5,-2.5),
category = c("red","red","blue","green","green"))
```

I want to plot an horizontal segment for each row of the dataframe. The line segments would be defined like this: `(x_ini[i],y[i])` and `(x_end[i],y[i])` and the color of segments by `line_df$category`.

I have tried with `geom_segment`, `segments`, `abline` and `lines` but I can't manage to set the legend properly and plotting the segments with the same instructions because I have other data I want to include on the same plot.

Any suggestion on how could I do this? Happy to modify the data frame to other more suitable structure but I want to avoid calling the same instruction several times for each one of the segments.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The other data I want to include is below.

```
previous_df <- data.frame(letter=c("x","y","y","z","x","p"),number=c(9,3,2,1,5,7),labeldf=c(1,15,12,15,1,12))

ggplot(previous_df,aes(labeldf,number,fill=letter)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position='dodge')
```

So the problem is that I can't add another `ggplot` layer to it, and if I add directly the `geom_segment` (mentioned in the answer by Nova) I get errors regarding the `fill` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you add a field for "row" you can do it - is this what you mean?

```
line_df$row <- seq_len(nrow(line_df))

ggplot(line_df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x_ini, xend = x_end, y = y, yend = y, 
                   group = row, color = category), size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("lightblue", "seagreen", "firebrick"))
```

[image]

If you want to add data from another dataframe, you could do it like this:

```
ggplot(previous_df) +
  geom_bar(aes(labeldf, number, fill=letter), stat="identity",position='dodge') +
  geom_segment(data = line_df, aes(x = x_ini, xend = x_end, y = y, yend = y, 
                                   group = row, color = category), size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("lightblue", "seagreen", "firebrick"))
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thanks! :) 
... but the problem is that it comes after another `ggplot` so I can't use it directly. I added an edit to my question giving more details, my guess is that there's some conflict when adding the two ggplot's but I haven't found out how to solve it.

Comment: @CristóbalRoderoGómez, try putting the "fill" parameter in your call to `geom_bar`, not your first call to `ggplot`. Please add a reproducible example if you would like further help - it's not clear which columns in your new dataframe are "x_ini" and "e_end".

Comment: In that case I get the error `Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : invalid color name 'x'` (it interprets the variables as color, whereas as ggplot parameter it interprets them as categories).

The `x_ini` variable is the one appearing in `line_df`, only that we have to specify that it's from that data frame since there are several ones.

So the `geom_segment` instruction would be `geom_segment(data=line_df,...`. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: I've attempted to create what I think you're after, but it's unclear to me what you want the final graph to look like.

Comment: Basically it would the bar graph (corresponding to the `previous_df` data frame) and underneath with the same axes etc. the line segments (described by the `line_df` data frame).